# Filling array- Angular Javascript

Tags: arrays

I have an empty object and array:

```
var aux = {};
var header = []
```

I have also a list of name that I d like to use to fill the header

```
var listOfNames = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

so what I want to do is to fill the header with it (I am just posting a really simple code that s why I have 2 loops when it s not needed but I need to check it in this way)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    var attribute = listOfNames[j];
    aux["Test"] = attribute;
    objectHeader.push(aux);
  }
  console.log(objectHeader);
 }
```

My idea, or what I though that I was doing, was to create an array of `length = 1` like the following:

```
[{Test: 0}, {Test: 1}, {Test: 2}]
```

but what I am getting is:

```
[{Test: 2}, {Test: 2}, {Test: 2}]
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Define `aux` in loop: `var aux = {}; aux['test'] = attribute; objectHeader.push(aux);`

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Easy and clear. Thank you mate

Comment: You can also achieve this using `array#map` `var header = listOfNames.map(Test => ({Test}));`

Answer (score 0):

Use the array method [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

Example: `[1, 2, 3].map(function(x) {return x*x})` creates a new array `[1, 4, 9]`

In your case:

`objectHeader = listOfNames.map(function(name){return {"Test":name}});`